# android detect LVL removal

Tags: android, android-lvl

I know it is impossible to prevent my app being cracked, either from antiLvl or luckypatch. For example, I downloaded antiLvl and cracked my own app within seconds. Rather, I would like to know if I can implement code to know that LVL is removed, and then send the information to a HTTP server, so I can know how many number of cracked version is over there. This may be useful for me to do evaluation. Thanks.

Comment: @rekire License Verification Library http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html

Comment: I can only guess that you could check periodically if that lib is aviable with reflection, or maybe you could check the signature of your app, that should be good hints.

Comment: how can i check if lib is aviable with reflection, any keyword? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. The most obvious mechanism is to use a lightweight hash function, such as CRC32, and build a hash of your application’s code.

```
PackageManager packagemanager = getPackageManager();
PackageInfo packageinfo = packagemanager.getPackageInfo(String packageName, int flags)
int hash = packageinfo.signatures[0].hashCode()
```

and compare it with original hash to check if it has been modified.

2.
Another approach that I have heard about is using Google NDK to create native library file {.so} and from there check if the apk has been tampered with or not.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: will keep that in mind.. new user. joined today only.

Comment: I've fixed your link. But you really should state the important parts of the link by editing your answer. I strongly recommend that you do it (plus, you'd get an upvote from me!)

Answer (score 1):

I use this code for testing if I have some trouble while building my app:

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    try {
        new com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment();
    } catch(NoClassDefFoundError e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "We got ActionBarSherlock problems");
    }
    try {
        new com.google.gson.Gson();
    } catch(NoClassDefFoundError e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "We got Gson problems");
    }
}
```

This should give you an idea, if you want to use this productive you should remove that outer if. I you are able you should also try to do this with reflection, I'm sure that proguard would remove this useless creations of objects.

Comment: so i can use "new com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker()" to check if it is removed. Btw, I added doCheck(); in Oncreate to check for license. Is that true that hacker can directly hacked the app and remove doCheck() and then by pass license check? thanks